# Why there is no bottom padding in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, padding

Why in the following code there is no bottom padding in Internet Explorer 8 ?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="a">Hello</div>
    <div class="a">Stack</div>
    <div class="a">Overflow</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.a {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Any workarounds for browser compatibility ?

Comment: Do you use a reset stylesheet?

Comment: @Icid: No, I don't, and I don't want to.

Comment: You should ;p Is really useful and solves ugly bugs now and then. This one especially: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

browser interpretation of the specs?

> A value of 'scroll' would tell UAs
>   that support a visible scrolling
>   mechanism to display one so that users
>   could access the clipped content.

Taken literally that means they, the browsers, can please themselves and they only have to provide access to the **content** not the padding or borders ;)

a compatible workaround:

```
#scroller {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.wrap {padding: 10px;}

.a {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="scroller">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="a">Hello</div>
    <div class="a">Stack</div>
    <div class="a">Overflow</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: LOL.. maybe because there'd be no challenge otherwise? `;)`

Answer (score 2):

How about going dirty? (Heck, I'm a programmer, not a designer lol).

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.a {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.b {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
.b {
    display:block;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="a">Hello</div>
    <div class="a">Stack</div>
    <div class="a">Overflow</div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

:D

Comment: Too dirty for me. Can't live with this solution.

Comment: My first thought was even dirtier. To use JQuery :D. The Horror!

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://edskes.net/ie8overflowandexpandingboxbugs.htm) post i think it will be helpful it did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

add display: block; to #wrapper {} - I had exactly the same issue, with this added padding-bottom started to work properly under IE8 and other browsers was not affected (keep the proper output)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pseudo-element «after» only for IE8:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```